# How to find out gridview's selected row position?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a text box and button inside a panel , and I want to show this panel right next to gridview selected row , gridview is also inside another panel , is there anyway to find out selected rows position ? This is a asp. Net page and I am using vb.net . Panel can be replaced by div

Appreciate your help .

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use the onRowCommand for the gridview :
[OnRowCommand][1]

```
First your database should have an id column with the identity(1,1) enabled.
```

Then you should add to your gridview:

```
onRowCommand = Row_Command
```

Then add a link button like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkButton" CommandName="Row_Command" CommandArgument='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("ID_COLUMN")) %>' Text="text"></asp:LinkButton>
```

finally in the code behind under the Row_Command:

Use the next line to avoid conflict with sorting and paging :

```
protected void reportComments(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
if (e.CommandName == "reportComments") {} }
```

and within the 'if' statment you can use this command to get the row position:

```
Something = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
```

and that should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , I looked into the link you provided it basically says how to add a button / link in gridview , that I already have done . What I need is position of selected row to display my comment panel right next to it .

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an extra column (hidden) to your gridview and put the panel with the text and button in that column, and then simply show the hidden cell when the row is selected?